# Why can't Spring 4 work out these generics correctly?

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring 4.3.7.RELEASE and am trying to implement a generic factory that decorates the objects it generates with a value supplied as a parameter.  Previously with Spring, I would not attempt the below as it would clearly run into issues with type erasure.  However, [since Spring 4](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics)  there has been proper (almost magical) support for instantiating generic types.

So, here is the code.  This is a contrived example to illustrate the point and isn't the actual code I am using.

First up, here is the generic interface that is the root of the hierarchy of objects that I wish to generate with the factory:

```
public interface Nameable {
    String getName();
    void setName(String name);
}
```

Next, there are 2 simple (identical for the example) classes that implement the interface:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class Foo implements Nameable {
    public Foo(){
        super();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private String name;
}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class Widget implements Nameable {
    public Widget(){
        super();
    }
    public Widget(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private String name;
}
```

Finally, here is the class that is the crux of everything, a generic factory for instances of `Nameable`:

```
@Component
public class NameableFactory<T extends Nameable> {
    @Autowired
    private ObjectFactory<T> objectFactory;

    public <T extends Nameable> T getObject(String name){
        T newObject = (T) this.objectFactory.getObject();

        newObject.setName(name);

        return newObject;
    }
}
```

There are also some additional client classes etc. that I have omitted.

At runtime, when the `getObject()` method of `NameableFactory<Foo>` or `NameableFactory<Widget>` is called, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Object' available: 
expected single matching bean but found 2: foo, widget
```

I have also tried this using `FactoryBean` instead of `ObjectFactory` and the result is identical.

I am pretty sure the answer to this is going to be: you can't do this because type erasure, probably on the grounds that Spring 4 can't handle a generic wrapped up in another generic (it's not magic, just clever illusion). However I thought I'd ask the community before giving up and implementing 20 odd factories by hand.

Also, I'd be totally open to a different approach that achieves the same goal so all manner of advice and pointers gratefully accepted.

**EDITS:**

1. Added `<T extends Nameable> T getObject()` in response to StanislavL comment
2. Removed caught Exception (throwback to FactoryBean version).

Comment: Could the person who downvoted the question leave some feedback as to how the question could be improved? Thanks!

Comment: should'nt be T implementing Nameable instead extending it? Not saying it solving your problem but seemed stange to me.

Comment: @Nemesis - thanks for the swift response. 'extends' is just the syntax used when declaring generics.  I did try switching it to 'implements' to see what happens but the compiler barfed big time.

Comment: I think what you're trying to do looks awkward here. Your Factories NameableFactory<Foo> or <Widget> call super() in constructors which is Object's constructor right? but then again your're trying to do the getObject() - which returns Object regardless of the Generic type set because it doesn't seem to have an identity set to it and returns Object. I think you should first call setName(name) possibly in constructor and then do your getObject() with appropriate casting etc or call it by name.The whole construction just looks confusing :) I think it just needs a bit of re-doing.

Comment: What about this `public <T extends Nameable> T getObject(String name)` ?

Comment: @Matt Iness Oups my bad not realy awaken here i think.

Comment: @StanislavL - good idea but that gives me the same error. I had thought it might give me No qualifying bean of type 'Nameable' but it's exactly the same.

Comment: @Sergey Benner - I've addressed part of what you've said by adding type information to the getObject() return type (also suggested by StanislavL ).  As to setName(), if I call it in the constructor I will need to pass it in as a parameter and then I cannot use ObjectFactory/FactoryBean as these require default constructor (if I understand correctly what you are suggesting). EDIT: Also superclass of Widget & Foo in real code is not Object

Comment: @MattInnes it's all good. Does it throw exception still?Update the question with the updated code please. :)

Comment: What is the class of the autowired ObjectFactory?

Comment: @Sergey Brenner - ah... the Exception catch was a hangover from the version that used FactoryBean instead of ObjectFactory (FactoryBean.getObject() throws Exception). I have removed it

Comment: @StanislavL - not sure if this is a trick or leading question :P but it's ObjectFactory<T> which is equivalent to ObjectFactory<Object> (in all cases).  So Spring can't work out which bean to use.  Even if Object were Nameable or some other common ancestor of Widget & Foo I'd have the same problem (with a different error probably). This I think is the root of my problem

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that spring can not figure out the generic type of your NameableFactory if you dont specify it at all

I've got an alternative idea for this factory:

```
public class NameableFactory {
    private Map<Class<? extends Nameable>, Supplier<Nameable>> map;

    public NameableFactory(Map<Class<? extends Nameable>, Supplier<Nameable>> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public Nameable get(Class<? extends Nameable> type, String name) {
        Nameable nameable = map.get(type)
        .get();
        nameable.setName(name);
        return nameable;
    }
}
```

And configure it this way.

```
@Configuration
public class FactoryConfig implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Bean
    public NameableFactory nameableFactory() {
        Map<Class<? extends Nameable>, Supplier<Nameable>> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(Foo.class, () -> ctx.getBean(Foo.class));
        map.put(Widget.class, () -> ctx.getBean(Widget.class));
        return new NameableFactory(map);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) throws BeansException {
        this.ctx = ctx;

    }
}
```

Comment: aussie - close but no cigar.  My NameableFactory is actually wrapped in another generic object (which holds multiple instances of Nameables).  So I can't use this approach as it depends on knowing the Class of the object you want to instantiate at runtime (which you can't do for Generics).  However I'll investigate using Suppliers as this could work for me

Comment: aussie - I tried this and ran into the same problem, No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.function.Supplier<?>' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: widget, foo.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to take a step back with this and dumb it down (deadlines ...).

Basically, I've taken a portion of aussie's answer (and upvoted as a result). In all classes where I need a `Widget` or a `Foo` I have added:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

private Widget getWidget(String name){
    Widget widget = applicationContext.getBean(Widget.class);
    widget.setName(name);
    return widget;
}
```

So I can leverage Spring instantiating the beans and their dependencies, but I lose the abstracting of the naming.  This is also quite alot of redundant typing but it's conceptually simple and it works.

Many thanks to those who offered suggestions, it's much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Matt, I had a similar (not same) problem and here's what I did: https://javawithravi.com/spring-generic-type-factory/ Please let me know if this was helpful?